# Average queue length in short-run at early stage

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Consider a simple M/M/1 queue (for example), with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$. Under the stability condition ($\lambda<\mu$), Queueing Theory says that the average queue length in long run is
$$E(L)=\frac{\rho^2}{1-\rho},$$
where $\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$. This is a common result.

However, to my surprise, I could not find any theory or papers (or maybe I could not catch the keyword to look for) that tackle the following seemingly simple question: What is the average queue length after the system has been run for the first $t$ time units (with the stability condition relaxed).

I would really appreciate any references.

Comment: Without doing any calculations, it would not surprise me if it was close to $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}t$ when $\lambda > \mu$

Comment: For any queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$, it can be shown that with probability 1: $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{L(t)}{t} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \lambda-\mu & \mbox{, if $\lambda > \mu$} \\ 0 & \mbox{, if $\lambda \leq \mu$}\end{array}\right.$$ This is shown for discrete time in Chapter 1 of this book ("rate stability theorem"), the case for continuous time is similar: https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00271ED1V01Y201006CNT007  For the M/M/1 queue with $L(0)=0$, the same holds for $E[L(t)/t]$, since you can uniformly bound $E[(L(t)/t)^2]$.

Comment: For $E[L(t)]$ for finite $t$ you can look up "transient behavior of M/M/1."  In general CTMCs you can describe transient behavior by a (sometimes messy) ODE.

Comment: There is a closed form result for the transient probability that $n$ customers are in the system at time $t$, given that the initial size is $0$, but it involves an infinite series of modified Bessel functions, which is not easy to work with.